# UiAutomator Accessing a child with limited information

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have a list of view that are built dynamically so they all have they exact same Resource id, and no description. The only way I can distinguish the difference between them is a text that is in the same parent. I am thinking the only way would be to do it like this:

```
Child >> parent >> child
```

[image]

As you can see above, I can get the child `MILES` or `CALORIES`. I need to get the text from the large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text from the large numbers views can be obtained. Let's suppose the layout is:

```
1. RelativeLayout
    0. Text View -> MILES
    1. Text View -> 0.50
2. RelativeLayout
    0. Text View -> CALORIES
    1. Text View -> 100

UiCollection resultsPage = new UiCollection(
            new UiSelector().className(android.widget.ListView.class.getName()));
UiObject resultLayout = resultsPage
            .getChildByText(new UiSelector()
                    .className(android.widget.RelativeLayout.class
                            .getName()), text); //where text can be MILES or CALORIES
UiObject score = resultLayout.getChild(new UiSelector()
            .resourceId(the resource id for the large text));
return (String) score.getText();
```

The idea is to isolate the two Relative layouts and search for the text within them, not the whole GUI. 
You can use uiautomatorviewer to look at the GUI layout. Maybe you could update the question with the detailed layout.

I could use that in order to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: "something general, that includes both views". What do you mean? The layout of the page? In my case: "android.widget.RelativeLayout"

Comment: This code will just take the first `relative layout` and not the one I am referencing... the resultsLayout has its own xml. and it gets added and altered to the xml layout. So all the boxes have the same info. Does this make sense?

Comment: Try to use uiautomatorviewer to look for a view that contains both text views that you are looking for. Could you tell me what app you are using or give me a detailed GUI layout?

Comment: I edited the answer. Try using android.widget.ListView where I wrote "something general". It looks to me that the views you are looking for are contained in a list view.